# Как запретить пользователям редактировать данные других пользователей

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-security, аутентификация, users

Есть задание, нужно написать на java rest api, в котором пользователи могут регистрироваться, создавать посты, комментарии и тп.
Понимаю как ограничить доступ пользователям к конкретным эндпоинтам. Но не понимаю как можно разрешить пользователю редактировать свой профиль, но запретить редактировать чужие профили.

Например: получаю конкретный пост пользователя с помощью гет запроса на урл myapp.com/post/id. Соответственно этот пост имеет одного владельца (который может его удалить, редактировать и тд) и многих читателей (которые могут поставить оценку), как определить кто может его редактировать, а кто нет.

По технологиям: spring boot, security, data, mvc.

P.S.: Понимаю что вопрос немного размытый, читать умею, если можно ссылку или название конкретных инструментов, почитаю сам.

Comment: Бэк знает кто выполняет запрос, авторизация есть?

Comment: Да, пока что basic, позже jwt token.

Comment: Тогда при выполнении действия просто сверяйте, если автор - то можно, если нет - нет. Или же проблема в чем-то другом?

Comment: нет, не в другом, не знаю как сверять)
Можно название класса, который содержит автора поста и запроса. Могу предположить что это Authentication. Верно?
А потом просто в сервисе выполнять проверку авторства.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте в поста поле `author_id`. Если он совпадает з пользователем - значит можно, если нет - нельзя.